# Assign information in filename to data tables

Tags: r

I wonder if it is possible to assign information from a filename into a data table in R.

For instance, I have thousands of csv file with the following format: **2007-Feb-Reservoir-Rain.csv**

What I need is:

- Put all the files in the directory in a list - like with `files = list.files()`
- Upload all those csvs at once, passing the info in their filename as variables within my table alongside the actual information in this table, which is just the milliliters of rain in a given month. I need to separate the infos by the dash (-), so it would look like:

[image]

Comment: What does the content of the CSV files look like? Are you saying they only contain one column, milliliters and all other information is in the file names? And by data table do you mean an object of class `data.table`, or just a regular data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `rbindlist()` function from the `data.table` package to add the information about each file when concatenating a list of `data.tables`:

```
library(data.table)

# Get a vector of file paths you want to load:
files <- list.files(path = ".", pattern = ".*-Rain.csv")

# Load those files into a list of data.tables:
dt_list <- lapply(files, fread)

# Name each list element after its file of origin:
names(dt_list) <- files

# Concatenate all files into a single data.table, with
# an additional column containing the filename each row 
# came from (taken from the names(dt_list))
dt <- rbindlist(dt_list, idcol = "file")

# Split the file name into three new columns:
dt[, year := as.numeric(sapply(strsplit(file, "-"), `[`, 1))]
dt[, month := sapply(strsplit(file, "-"), `[`, 2)]
dt[, type := sapply(strsplit(file, "-"), `[`, 3)]

# Remove the filename column since its no longer needed
dt[, file := NULL]
```

Comment: tstrsplit may be even better

Comment: I think there are better tidyverse options for splitting a column - i just can't recall them off the top of my head (i mostly get by with gsub)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an approach using the `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)

# List all csv files including sub-folders
list_of_files <- list.files(path = ".", recursive = TRUE,
                            pattern = "\\.csv$", full.names = TRUE)

# Loop through all the files using map_df, read data using read_csv 
# and create a FileName column to store filenames
# Then clean up filename: remove file path and extension
# Finally separate Filename into 4 columns using "-" as separator
df <- list_of_files %>%
  purrr::set_names(nm = (basename(.) %>% tools::file_path_sans_ext())) %>%
  purrr::map_df(readr::read_csv, .id = "FileName") %>% 
  tidyr::separate(FileName, c("year", "month", "type", "milliliters"), "-")
```

Comment: thank you, tung, I will try this out as well, purr is great, but I am stil learning it